# Kubuntu gets hung up on udev whenever installing anything

Tags: kubuntu, udev

I have just installed Kubuntu 15 and I am an Ubuntu newbie .

Everything went swimmingly during the install (I'm using the computer now) but when I click on the little red shield update button or if I try to download any software via the software centre, it gets to 'configuring udev' or 'udev' (respectively) and just seems to stay there.

I have googled a fair bit but the only question that seemed to make any sense to me was one where the user suggested that the ISP bandwidth squeeze had scuppered an update and so he needed to delete the first set of files downloaded before restarting. That only makes sense to me because, having downloaded the OS in the first place I can imagine the 100 odd updates it suggested would have alarmed Mr Murdoch's broadband company.

Unfortunately, I can't even figure out how to use the command line, let alone figure out whether that's my issue. I still call '/' an oblique.

Anyone kind enough to try to help me?

Comment: Welcome to AU !   Sorry can't help you with Kubuntu, but when you want to quote a post, whether on AU or not,  you can do so using the _Hyperlink_  (third from left) icon above your post-edition window. Good luck with all. You will get an answer !

Comment: I didn't:( but upgrading the OS solved the problem. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: If you solved yr prbm, please post an ***answer*** to yr own question and check the green mark next to it to identify it as the answer. That way others will benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the OS solved the problem. No clue why.